# ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName failing on module cmdlet

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-cmdlet

I have a cmdlet called `Get-Organization` which returns the below as return type

```
public class OrgModel
{
    public string OrgName {get;set;}
}

[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Organization")]
[OutputType(typeof(OrgModel))]
 public GetOrganizationCmdlet : PSCmdlet
    {

        [Alias("OrgName")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "The orgname.")]
        string Name{get;set}

        ...
    }
```

I have another cmdlet called `Department` which returns a model `DepartmentModel`. `Get-Department -OrgName <somename>` returns all departments inside the `Orgname`. The cmdlet is defined as below.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Department")]
public GetDepartmentCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, Position = 0, HelpMessage = "The org name.")]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
        string OrgName {get;set}

    [Parameter(Mandatory = false, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true, Position = 1, HelpMessage = "Optional. The department name.")]
        string Name{get;set}

    ...
}
```

After loading the module, everything works as expected. The place where it breaks is piping. The below returns an error

`Get-Organization -Name <somename> | Get-Department`

As you can see, the return type `OrgModel` has a property defined called `OrgName` which should automatically bind to `Get-Department` parameter `OrgName` but it is not and giving the below error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Organization -Name contoso | Get-Department
Get-Department : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:44
+ ... et-Organization -Name contoso | Get-Department
+                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (OrgModel:PSObject) [Get-Department], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,GetDepartment
```

Any idea ?

Comment: try changing the name parameter of GetOrganizationCmdlet to orgname?

Comment: Show output of `Get-Organization -Name <somename> | Get-Member` and `(Get-Command Get-Department).ParameterSets`.

Comment: yeah, gm is a logical question, but i assumed that person did it already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the command that @PeterSerAl mentioned I noticed the return time was incorrectly set to a collection.

It works after fixing it.

Thanks